# Convert a whole Xdocument in an array

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I am stuck on a project which needs to exchange data between two programs who have different coontrol files.
Program A just creates a a XML File whereas Program B needs the input as an array with two "columns" - but how do can I do the conversion?

Example:
The xml looks like:

```
` <Presentation>
  <Options Name="1">
  <Output>MyOutPut</Output>
    <Slides Name="1">
    <Template>Template2</Template> 
      <Diagram Name="Name4">
         <More Elements...>
      </Diagram>
    </Slides>
    </Options>
  </Presentation>`
```

The output should like this:

```
 `
    Presentation ""
    Options 1
    Output Myoutput
    Slides 1
    Template Template2

...
`
```

But how can I achieve this? I am using vb.net and LINQ and have no idea how to solve this problem. I tried some LINQ queries but I get only indivudal nodes or attributes so I think it would be better to try a different idea.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Read about [preorder traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_traversal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, I cannot provide `VB` code, but I hope this `C#` snippet will help.

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = XElement.Load(@"path-to-the-file");

    doc.DescendantsAndSelf()
       .Select(ElementSelector).Dump();
}

private static KeyValuePair<string, string> ElementSelector(XElement e)
{
    var name = e.Name.ToString();
    var value = String.Empty;
    if (e.Descendants().Any())
    {
        if (e.Attributes().Any())
        {
            value = e.Attributes().First().Value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        value = e.Value;
    }
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name, value);
}
```

Comment: Hello RePierre,
your answer nailed my problem on the spot.

The conversion from c# to vb.net is easy, tahnks to automatic conversion tools.
However, vb.net does not know dump, so I had to do a slight modification:

´    Private Sub Main()
        Dim doc = XElement.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & Constants.tempXML)

        Dim Dump = doc.DescendantsAndSelf().Select(AddressOf ElementSelector)
        Dim list = Dump.ToList

        For Each elem In list
            Debug.Print(elem.Key & elem.Value)
        Next

    End Sub´

Can you provide some information what ElementSelect does?

Comment: @ChristianSauer, I've tested the code in **LINQPad** and `Dump()` is a built-in method that writes the results to console. `ElementSelector` is the method that converts an `XElement` object to a key-value pair; each element of your document is _projected_ by the `ElementSelector` method into a key-value pair.